# Импорт постов разными пользователями одновременно wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Стоит задача: сделать импорт постов во фронте админки пользователя.**
Данные как мы понимаем можно получать откуда угодно (например: файл импорта, по API и т д). Но непонятно, что произойдет, если в одно и то же время пользователи ( для примера 2-3 пользователя ) будут загружать свои посты, как это отразится на нагрузке сервера и смогут ли пользователи пользоваться сайтом в это время? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Сымитировать 2-3 пользователей загружающих посты - плевое дело.

Comment: 2-3 это просто ни о чём, даже на самом простом хостинге.

Comment: вопрос не в том чтобы сымитировать, вопрос в том, как это реализовать. я могу написать простой код для импорта данных и на этом все?

Comment: курим "блокировка транзакций базы данных". Ну и маны по хайлоаду.  Там это чуть ли не в первых строках пишется.